# AWS Redshift with Excel

Tags: excel, amazon-redshift

I want to connect my redshift database to excel so i can easly analysis and make report in excel but iam not able to can anyone please help me how to do that, thank you in advance

I want to make dynamic report of tables present in redshift in Excel

Comment: Have you considered integrating Redshift with Amazon QuickSight and exporting data from QuickSight to .xslx files?

Answer (score 0):

I did this for a client some years ago.  There are several articles on setting up Excel to connect directly to Redshift .  Here's a few examples - https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/redshift-odbc-excel-query.rst or https://hevodata.com/learn/excel-to-redshift/